# Debian Bullseye + Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi no wifi interface

Tags: debian, networking, wifi, intel, iwlwifi

After some update and then crash (the origin story is blurry), the wifi was gone. I was then on Ubuntu 20.04 but did a clean reinstall with Debian with the non-free firmwares.

Nonetheless the problem persisted. I read every question I could on the Internet but so far no luck. So:

- Clean reinstall with Debian 10 and then move to bullseye
- `firmware-iwlwifi` and `firmware-misc-nonfree` are installed
- Network card seen with `lspci`: Network controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi
- No soft/hard block (check with `rfkill`)
- `ifconfig` only shows the ethernet and the loopback interface
- `dmesg | grep iwlconfig`:

```
[   50.232084] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   50.232085] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
[   50.514718] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 535 at /home/chris/backport-iwlwifi/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/pcie/drv.c:973 iwl_pci_probe+0x503/0x590 [iwlwifi]
[   50.514719] Modules linked in: btrtl pcc_cpufreq(-) uvcvideo(+) nls_ascii btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_core irqbypass btintel nls_cp437 videobuf2_memops iwlwifi(OE+) intel_cstate videobuf2_v4l2 efi_pstore snd_hwdep intel_uncore videobuf2_common vfat iTCO_wdt joydev bluetooth videodev iTCO_vendor_support snd_pcm fat intel_rapl_perf pcspkr snd_timer mc cfg80211(OE) serio_raw watchdog efivars intel_wmi_thunderbolt drbg ansi_cprng snd ecdh_generic ecc soundcore compat(OE) intel_pch_thermal rfkill tpm_crb tpm_tis tpm_tis_core tpm rng_core intel_hid evdev sparse_keymap acpi_pad ac parport_pc ppdev lp parport efivarfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic dm_crypt dm_mod i915 crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper rtsx_pci_sdmmc cec mmc_core nvme ahci libahci nvme_core aesni_intel rtsx_pci r8169 xhci_pci mfd_core libaes t10_pi realtek crc_t10dif crypto_simd xhci_hcd libata libphy cryptd glue_helper crct10dif_generic drm psmouse
[   50.514796] RIP: 0010:iwl_pci_probe+0x503/0x590 [iwlwifi]
[   50.514868]  iwl_pci_register_driver+0x21/0x40 [iwlwifi]
[   50.514898]  __init_backport+0xc2/0x1000 [iwlwifi]
[   50.640213] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -22
```

Note: there is a weird issue with the bluetooth, `dmesg | grep blue`:

```
[   50.514719] Modules linked in: btrtl pcc_cpufreq(-) uvcvideo(+) nls_ascii btbcm videobuf2_vmalloc snd_hda_core irqbypass btintel nls_cp437 videobuf2_memops iwlwifi(OE+) intel_cstate videobuf2_v4l2 efi_pstore snd_hwdep intel_uncore videobuf2_common vfat iTCO_wdt joydev bluetooth videodev iTCO_vendor_support snd_pcm fat intel_rapl_perf pcspkr snd_timer mc cfg80211(OE) serio_raw watchdog efivars intel_wmi_thunderbolt drbg ansi_cprng snd ecdh_generic ecc soundcore compat(OE) intel_pch_thermal rfkill tpm_crb tpm_tis tpm_tis_core tpm rng_core intel_hid evdev sparse_keymap acpi_pad ac parport_pc ppdev lp parport efivarfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 ext4 crc16 mbcache jbd2 crc32c_generic dm_crypt dm_mod i915 crc32_pclmul crc32c_intel ghash_clmulni_intel i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper rtsx_pci_sdmmc cec mmc_core nvme ahci libahci nvme_core aesni_intel rtsx_pci r8169 xhci_pci mfd_core libaes t10_pi realtek crc_t10dif crypto_simd xhci_hcd libata libphy cryptd glue_helper crct10dif_generic drm psmouse
[   50.799428] bluetooth hci0: firmware: failed to load intel/ibt-17-0-0.sfi (-2)
[   50.799477] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-17-0-0.sfi failed with error -2
```

And I can't find that version of the firmware online.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you add the output of `lspci -knn |grep Net -A3` and `uname -a`. Please.

Comment: @chris are you user420942? If see then get your accounts merged.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a Kernel bug that got fixed *very* recently and might be included in Kernel 5.7.8, easy solution is to use a less recent Kernel (>v5.7).

https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/66977

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=290037&action=diff